# Java code is not executing instance method

Tags: java, bluej

I am using the BlueJ IDE. I have a main class entitled `ProgramOne`, and another class `StarTurtle` (intended to serve an instance method).

Here is the code of `ProgramOne`:

```
public class ProgramOne
{
     public static void main (String[ ] args)  
     {  
          StarTurtle turtle1 = new StarTurtle(5);
          turtle1.StartTurtle();

        }
    }
```

Here is the code of `StarTurtle`:

```
public class StarTurtle 
{ 

private int points;      

public int StartTurtle(int x) 
{ 
points = x; 

Turtle sue;
sue = new Turtle();
sue.paint (90, 40); 

} 

}
```

(The `turtle` method you see is from two other classes that I have not pasted here for the sake of brevity. These classes are found in the http://www.cs.ccsu.edu/~jones/book.htm manual)

The code only compiles, and there is no option to execute. However, there is no option to execute `void main (String[ ] args)`, which there should be to execute the main class. Does anyone know what is the cause of this? I am assuming that there is a problem in the code itself.

**Edit:** When I mean "option to execute", I am referring to this BlueJ functionality:

[image: BlueJ]

**Edit:** Changing the code in the manner which Titus and Redge described (in the answers and comments of answers) fixed the `StarTurtle` class, but the main class `ProgramOne` still does not execute.

Comment: what do you mean with "option to execute"?

Comment: um ... you are showing the solution to your own question in your screenshot ...

Comment: The `StarTurtle` doesn't have any constructor which takes an `int`, `public int StartTurtle(int x) ` is a method not a constructor and you are calling it from the `main` method without any parameters, as it is, this code won't compile.

Comment: how does this code even compile?

Comment: So how would that be fixed? @titus

Comment: For your own sake, please move on to Eclipse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So ... I was previously unfamiliar with BlueJ but I just downloaded it and created the code that we have all been suggesting. It now looks like this.

ProgramOne.java

```
public class ProgramOne
{
     public static void main (String[ ] args)  
     {  
          StarTurtle turtle1 = new StarTurtle();
          turtle1.StartTurtle(5);

     }
}
```

StarTurtle.java

```
public class StarTurtle 
{ 

    private int points;      

    public void StartTurtle(int x) 
    { 
        points = x; 

        Turtle sue;
        sue = new Turtle();
        sue.paint (90, 40); 

    } 

}
```

With this code the context menu looks exactly like the one in the original question:

[image]

The menu item that reads `void main(String[] args)` pops up a dialog as follows :

[image: dialog]

If I hit the OK button I seem to get a window called "Turtle Drawings" that contains a vertical line.

I changed the StartTurtle(int) method as follows:

```
    public void StartTurtle(int x) 
    { 
        points = x; 

        Turtle sue;
        sue = new Turtle(true, 200,90);
        sue.sleep(1000);
        sue.say("Something");
        sue.sleep(1000);
        sue.paint (90, 40); 
        sue.sleep(1000);
        sue.fillCircle(5);
        sue.sleep(1000);
        sue.fillBox(10, 20);

    } 

}
```

This modified code displays the message, a vertical line, a circle and then a rectangle at 1 second intervals.

I can only conclude from this that the code is now valid and that you should execute it by chosing the menu item that reads `void main(String{} args)`.

Comment: How would I make the turtle global, so that it could be declared in the main class and then used in the method?

Comment: I don't understand what  you mean by global. Java is object oriented so  the concept of global is a bit foreign. Could you explain what you want to do?

Comment: You're right, Java is my first forray into OO programming- when I mean global, I mean declaring a variable whose scope can be accessed from any class. @redge

Comment: The closest thing to that would be to declare it as a static field say `public static final StarTurtle turtle1 = new StarTurtle ();` you would do this before the main method in `Program One` instead of in the method and then you can just call `ProgramOne.turtle1.StartTurtle (5)` in the main method or in fact anywhere else.

Comment: Thank you. When I asked that question/comment, I didn't realize that the course wanted to use `extend` for classes to inherit their variables. I guess that's the OO way! :) @redge

Answer (score 1):

The `StarTurtle` doesn't have any constructor which takes an int,

```
public int StartTurtle(int x)
```

is a method not a constructor and you are calling it from the `main` method without any parameters, as it is, this code won't compile.

You can change the code to something like this.

```
 public static void main (String[ ] args) {  
      StarTurtle turtle1 = new StarTurtle();
      int result = turtle1.StartTurtle(5);

 }
```

To respect the Java conventions you should consider starting method names with a lowercase.

Comment: I'm aware of camel-casing, but the course I am taking doesn't require or even ask of it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the code still does not execute.

Comment: @seanlevan I haven't user BlueJ but probably the option to execute doesn't show up because your code can't be compiled, from the code that you've posted no other problem is evident.

Comment: ` int startTurtle (int) ` does not actually return a result so it should either be ` void StartTurtle (int)`  and not be assigned to anything or it should end with a return statement.

Comment: Don't respect the conventions because they are a requirement, respect them because it will make coding easier, if you will have done that, you would have noticed that `StartTurtle(int i)` is a method not a constructor.

Comment: @redge it returns an `int`, the method is `public` **int** `StartTurtle(int x)`, are we looking at the same code ?

Comment: Sorry, I corrected my comment, I was referring to the internal code which was inconsistent with the signature.

Comment: @redge Changing the code as you said (to void) fixed the problem for the StarTurtle class... which is good! Thanks! However, the main class still cannot be executed.

Comment: I noticed that `Turtle.paint (...)` takes 2 doubles. Try changing the arguments to `paint (90D, 40D)`

Comment: That doesn't change anything- moreover, I have used paint in the same manner many times before... I am desperate! @redge

Comment: Furthermore, the StarTurtle class works now... but the main class doesn't. @redge

Comment: Have you changed the code as follows and as suggested by Titus?          StarTurtle turtle1 = new StarTurtle();
            turtle1.StartTurtle(5);

Answer (score 0):

Change

`public int StartTurtle(int x)`

to this

`public StartTurtle(int x)`

You wrote about `StartTurtl` class:

> intended to serve an instance method

My question is - what is `instance method` ??

Comment: instance methods are non-static methods - they require individual instances.

Comment: Thank you, I just reffer to such methods well just methods.

Comment: Still doesn't work- I added `int` after it didn't execute originally.

Comment: Change IDE eg. Eclipse. No problems with running there.

Comment: Thank my AP Java course. Every one of those courses that I have tried require BlueJ, yet I absolutely hate it- it's supposedly for beginners, but for me it just complicates matters.

Comment: Is it a programming course, or using BlueJ course how-to ?? If programming, change ide

Comment: Programming, but assignments have to be turned in using project files which are BlueJ-based. @Antoniossss

Comment: If BJ mangles your code into their specific types then that's more of a reason to switch. Courses at my school rarely require a specific IDE; they only suggest that you *don't* use ones like BlueJ, JGrasp... @seanlevan

Comment: Mine requires me to use BlueJ. That is why I tagged my question with a tag called "bluej", because my question might be pertinent to that specific IDE. @ChiefTwoPencils